# Call a function from the console as an argument

Tags: python, linux, function, console, arguments

I have a `file1.py`:

```
def battery():
    pass

// much more methods here

if __name__ == "__main__":
    cmd = str((sys.argv)[1]) + "()"
    os.system(cmd)
```

Now I want to call `file1.battery()` from the linux console with `python file1.py battery`.

But I get the error:

```
sh: 1: Syntax error: end of file unexpected
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [eval](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#eval) for compiling string like code or use **globals** and **locals**:

```
def func():
    return 'hello'

print eval('func()')
print globals()["func"]()
print locals()["func"]()

>>> hello
>>> hello
>>> hello
```

Also, the module can import itself:

```
import sys

current_module = sys.modules[__name__]
function = getattr(current_module, 'func')
print function()
```

Comment: to note, the use of eval is extremely dangerous when considering user input. `eval(rm -rf /)` not good.